# nodejs http post request throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make a simple server that use google oauth (without express and passportjs, as I want to study the data exchanged).

When my program attempts to send a post request to google, nodejs throws:

```
http.js:593 throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
```

I have checked and make sure that all parameters in query and option are all string, but the error still persist. What could I have missed here?

Here is my code:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var content;

fs.readFile('./test.html',function(err,data){
    content = data;
});

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  var query = querystring.parse(url.parse(request.url).query);
  var code;
  if (query!=null) {
    code = query.code;
  };

  if ('/auth/google/callback'==path){

    var data = querystring.stringify({
        'code':          ''+code,
        'client_id':     'id',
        'client_secret': 'secret',
        'redirect_uri':  'http://localhost:8999/auth/google/code/callback',
        'grant_type':    'authorization_code'
    });

    var options = {
        hostname: 'accounts.google.com',
        port:'80',
        path: '/o/oauth2/token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Content-Length': ''+data.length
      }
    };

    debugger;
    var post = http.request(options, function(res){
        response.write(res);
        response.end();
    });
    debugger;
    post.write(data);
    debugger;
    post.end();
  }

  else if (path=='/auth/google/code/callback'){
    console.log(request.headers);
    console.log(request.url);
  }

  else response.end(content);

  console.log(request.headers);
  console.log(request.url);
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8999);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Many thanks,

Comment: when are you making the post request ?

Comment: post.end(), I assume, is when the request is sent.

Comment: i think you are saying `response.write(res)`  here res is a object see `console.log(typeof(res))`.

Comment: Thanks alot Mritunjay, silly me, the content is a json object.

Comment: did u got the solution of your problem?

Comment: Hi Mrit, the problem seem to belong to another aspect now. Which is handling https communication with Google Oauth.However, the answer you provided, I think, did address the main problem of this question. THanks alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think problem is when you are saying

```
response.write(res); //it needs a string
```

I think `res` is an object here.

try

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was at the response.write as you said. But, it seem the res body is actually an html of redirecting message rather than Json, so JSON.stringify does not work here.

Comment: @MikeNQ ok no prob, then let this question open.

Answer (score 0):

When you write response or request. It should contain string so you need to change it to

```
response.write(querystring.stringify(res));
```

or

```
response.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```